# Raspberry Python Crontab script problem with timestamp

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I edited a script that i found online for control a pwm fan and i added an if block to write a log to a file "fan.log" every 5 minutes. I run the script through crontab. Everything is working but i don't understand why the timestamp is 5 minutes behind the current time. If i run the script manually without crontab, the time is correct.
Someone can help me understand?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import RPi.GPIO as IO                   # Calling GPIO to allow use of the GPIO pins
import time                     # Calling time to allow delays to be used
import subprocess                   # Calling subprocess to get the CPU temperature

boardPort = 18                      # GPIO
fanFreq = 2000                      # Freq

IO.setwarnings(False)                   # Do not show any GPIO warnings
IO.setmode(IO.BCM)                  # BCM pin numbers - PIN8 as ‘GPIO14’
IO.setup(boardPort,IO.OUT)              # Initialize GPIO18 as our fan output pin
fan = IO.PWM(boardPort,fanFreq)             # Set GPIO18 as a PWM output, with 2000Hz frequency
fan.start(0)                        # Generate a PWM signal with a 0% duty cycle (fan off)

minTemp = 40                        # Temperature and speed range variables
maxTemp = 70
minSpeed = 0
maxSpeed = 100

count = -1

def get_temp():                     # Function to read in the CPU temperature
    output = subprocess.run(['vcgencmd', 'measure_temp'], capture_output=True)
    temp_str = output.stdout.decode()
    try:
        return float(temp_str.split('=')[1].split('\'')[0])
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        raise RuntimeError('Could not get temperature')

def renormalize(n, range1, range2):         # Function to scale the read temperature to the fan speed range
    delta1 = range1[1] - range1[0]
    delta2 = range2[1] - range2[0]
    return (delta2 * (n - range1[0]) / delta1) + range2[0]

while 1:                        # Execute loop forever
    cels = get_temp()
    temp = cels                     # Get the current CPU temperature
    if temp < minTemp:                  # Constrain temperature to set range limits
        temp = minTemp
    elif temp > maxTemp:
        temp = maxTemp
    temp = int(renormalize(temp, [minTemp, maxTemp], [minSpeed, maxSpeed]))
    fan.ChangeDutyCycle(temp)               # Set fan duty based on temperature, from minSpeed to maxSpeed
    count += 1

    if count % 10 == 0:
        timeStr = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
        f = open("/home/pi/FanControl/fan.log", "w")
        f.write(timeStr + " - La temperatura è di " + str(cels) + "°C e la ventola è al " + str(temp) + "%.\n")
        f.close
        if count == 1000:
            count = 0

    time.sleep(30)                  # Sleep for 30 seconds
```

Comment: Side note: you close file handle incorrectly (in fact you do not close it at all) as `f.close` should be `f.close()` (with brackets). I also suggest you swich to `with open ....` statement

Comment: It was simple as @MarcinOrlowski suggested. I simply typed it wrong and forgot the parentheses in the close statement. The file remain opened and when i try to read it i read the previous session.
Stupid error. Thanks